# jQuery ajax call to php process form page not returning success or error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a contact page with a `HTML Form`.

I use `jQuery` to validate the fields. Then use `jQuery's .ajax()` method to send the information to the php file that processes and sends out the email via the `mail()` method.

Inside the `PHP File` i have an `IF` statement that checks to see if a `POST variable` is set that way I can put all form processing on one page for multiple forms through out the website.

I get all variables and do another form field validation with `PHP`. Then I build out the `HTML Email` and it's headers.

If the PHP Validation is successful I then send the email via the `mail()` method. Then I check if the `mail()` method was successful and if so I send another "auto reply" email.

Inside of the `IF` statements that check to see if the `mail()` method was successful I `echo` a success or error message with `json_encode()`.

When the user clicks the submit button on the form I have it set to return false so it stays on the same page and have a message displayed upon send success.

Both emails send successfully from the form. Except my `.ajax()` method does not receive the success or error message from the php files' `json_encode()`.

I removed the return false in the jQuery .click and have tried a standard `PHP echo` inside the php `IF` statement that checks if the post `isset()` and I couldn't get it to print to the browser. nor does the `json_encode` print to the browser. However, when I put the `PHP echo` outside of the `IF` statement it printed just fine. Which confuses me because it obviously goes inside that if statement to send the email but won't echo. What am I doing wrong?

**jQuery**

```
$("#contactFormSubmit").click(function(){

      // validate and process form here

        // NAME VALIDATION
        var name = $("input#nameField").val();
        if (name == "") {
            $("input#nameField").focus();
            $("input#nameField").css("border","1px solid red");
            alert("nameFieldError");
            return false;
        }

        // EMAIL VALIDATION
        var formEmail = $("input#emailField").val();
        if (formEmail == "" || !validateEmail(formEmail)) {
            $("input#emailField").focus();
            $("input#emailField").css("border","1px solid red");
            alert("emailFieldError");
            return false;
        }

        // PHONE VALIDATION
        var phone = $("input#phoneField").val();

        var phoneReg = "/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/";

        if (phone == "" || !isValidUSPhoneFormat(phone)) {
            //alert("phone is wrong");
            $("input#phoneField").focus();
            $("input#phoneField").css("border","1px solid red");
            alert("phoneFieldError");
            return false;   
        }

        var message = $("textarea#messageField").val();

        var subject = $("#subjectField").val();

        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + formEmail + '&phone=' + phone + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message + '&submitContactForm=1';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process-form.php",
            data: dataString,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function(response) {

                if(response.status === "success") {
                    alert("success");
                    // do something with response.status or other data on success

                } else if(response.status === "error") {
                    alert("error");
                    // do something with response.status or other data on error

                }   

            },
            error: function(xhr,errmsg) { alert(errmsg); }
        });
        return false;      
    });
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php
include "includes/functions.php";

if(isset($_POST['submitContactForm'])) {

$nextEventDay = getDay();
$eventToShow = "";
$dayToShow = "";
$dateToShow = "";

if ($nextEventDay == "Sunday" || $nextEventDay == "Monday" || $nextEventDay == "Tuesday" || $nextEventDay == "Wednesday" ||$nextEventDay == "Thursday" || $nextEventDay != "Friday" || $nextEventDay != "Saturday") {
    $eventToShow = "thurEvent";
    $dayToShow = "THU";
    $dateToShow = getNextThursdayDate();
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$messageBody = $_POST['message'];

$sendTo = "xxxx@xxxx.com";
$confirmTo = $email;

//HTML EMAIL
        $headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        //COMPANY EMAIL
        $message5 = '<html><style type="text/css">table, td, tr, th{border:none !important;border-color:#111 !important;border-collapse:collapse;}a{color:#c92626 !important;}.title{color:#aaa;}</style><body style="background-color: #111;color:#ddd;border:2px solid #333;">';
        $message5 .= '<table rules="all" style="background-color:#111;border:none !important;width:100%;" cellpadding="10" border="0">';
        $message5 .= '<tr style="border:none;"><td style="border:none;padding:20px 0px !important;"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Nightclub" style="display:block;margin:0 auto;min-width:260px;max-width:300px;width:50%;" width="260" /></td></tr>';
        $message5 .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;'><img src='/images/" . $eventToShow . "-email-next-event.jpg' width='260' style='min-width:260px;max-width:1024px;width:100%;display:block;margin: 0 auto;' /></td></tr>";
        $message5 .= "<tr style='border:none;background-color:#161616;'><td style='border:none;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Name:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . strip_tags($name) . "</td></tr>";
        $message5 .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;' class='title' ><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Email:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color:#c92626 !important;'>" . strip_tags($email) . "</span></td></tr>";
        $message5 .= "<tr style='border:none;background-color:#161616;' ><td style='border:none;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Phone:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color:#c92626 !important;'>" . strip_tags($phone) . "</span></td></tr>";
        $message5 .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Subject:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . strip_tags($subject) . "</td></tr>";
        $message5 .= "<tr style='border:none;background-color:#161616;' ><td style='border:none;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Message:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . strip_tags($messageBody) . "</td></tr>";
        $message5 .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;'></td></tr>";
        $message5 .= "</table>";
        $message5 .= "</body></html>";

        //CLIENT EMAIL
        $areply = '<html><style type="text/css">table, td, tr, th {border:none !important;border-color:#111 !important;border-collapse:collapse;}a {color:#c92626 !important;}.title{color:#aaa;}#date a{color:#fff !important;text-decoration:none;}</style><body style="background-color: #111;color:#ddd;border:2px solid #333;">';
        $areply .= "<table rules='all' style='background-color:#111;border:none !important;width:100%;' cellpadding='10' border='0'>";

        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;padding:20px 0px !important;'><img src='images/logo.jpg' alt='Nightclub Ann Arbor' style='display:block;margin:0 auto;min-width:260px;max-width:300px;width:50%;' width='260' /></td></tr>";

        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;'><img src='images/" . $eventToShow . "-email-next-event.jpg' width='260' style='min-width:260px;max-width:1024px;width:100%;display:block;margin: 0 auto;' /></td></tr>";

        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none; background:#151515;'><td style='border:none;text-align:justify;background-color:#161616;'><div style='float:left;display:inline-block;background-color:#000;margin:0px 10px 10px 0px;font-size:197%; padding: 25px 30px;'><p id='date' style='margin:0;color:#fff !important;'> \r\n <strong>" . $dateToShow ."</strong></p><p style='margin:0;color:#c92626 !important;'>" . $dayToShow ."</p></div><p style='margin-top:10px;margin-right:15px;'>Thank you for contacting us at Nightclub . We look forward to assisting you. Below is the information that we recieved and we will be contacting you as soon as possible. Thank you again, and we look forward to speaking with you. If you have any additional questions please contact us at our website (<a href='' style='color:#c92626'></a>), give us a call <span style='color:#c92626 !important;'></span>, or send us an Email <span style='color:#c92626 !important;'></span></p></td></tr>";

        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Name: </strong>" . strip_tags($name) . "</td></tr>";
        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none; background-color:#161616 !important;' ><td style='border:none !important;background-color:#161616 !important;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Email:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color:#c92626 !important;'>" . strip_tags($email) . "</span></td></tr>";

        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Phone:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='color:#c92626 !important;'>" . strip_tags($phone) . "</span></td></tr>";
        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none;background-color:#161616;' ><td style='border:none;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Subject:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . strip_tags($subject) . "</td></tr>";
        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;' class='title'><strong style='color:#aaa;'>Message:</strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . strip_tags($messageBody) . "</td></tr>";
        $areply .= "<tr style='border:none;'><td style='border:none;'></td></tr>";
        $areply .= "</table>";
        $areply .= "</body></html>";

        $subject2 = "Thank you for your expressed interest ()";
        $noreply = "xxx@xxx.com";   

        $headers2 = "From: " . $noreply . "\r\n";
        $headers2 .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers2 .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

        if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($phone) || !preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/',$email) || !preg_match("/^(\d[\s-]?)?[\(\[\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\)\]\s-]{0,2}?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$/i",$phone)) {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 'error'
                //'message'=> 'error message'
            ));
        } else {
            $send = mail($sendTo, $subject, $message5, $headers);

        }
        if($send){
            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 'success'
                //'message'=> 'success message'
            ));

            $send2 = mail($email, $subject2, $areply, $headers2);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 'error'
                //'message'=> 'success message'
            ));
        }

}
?>
```

**UPDATE**
I added the error call back to the `jQuery ajax()` method and found I was receiving the error I also removed everything from my PHP file except for the:

```
            echo json_encode(array(
                'status' => 'success'
                //'message'=> 'success message'
            ));
```

And I still get the error message from the `jQuery ajax()` method. So it must be in my jQuery code... I think.

Comment: I would recommend PHP heredoc syntax for writing long HTML strings like this.

Comment: I don't see the ajax call anywhere in your code...

Comment: add an `error` callback along side your `success` callback to see if the request is erroring out. Also check your php server logs to check for reported errors

Comment: @PatrickEvans are you talking about an error call back in the jQuery or the PHP json_encode?

Comment: in the jQuery.ajax options add a error callback similar to the success: `error:function(xhr,errmsg){ alert(errmsg); }`

Comment: @PatrickEvans Ok, I did. It sends alert but just says error

Comment: That means your request is erroring out, check your server logs to see why

Comment: @PatrickEvans My error log files aren't showing anything. They are empty. saying 0 bytes. Customer support is saying it usually takes up to 24 hours to view error logs. really? thats crazy.

Comment: Check your firebug console. You should see the request and response right there.

Comment: Thanks @MartyMcKeever I solved it using the firebug console. Apparently one of my PHP functions was throwing an error because I didn't pass in an argument. Once I put an argument in the PHP function everything works perfectly. Awesome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so thanks to the advice from @PatrickEvans and @MartyMcKeever above, I solved it by looking at the firebug console to find out that one of my custom PHP functions was missing a required argument. This was causing a parse error which was then making my jQuery throw an error but still allow the PHP to process the email.

If you look at the above PHP code there is a method that says `$nextEventDay = getDay();`

It should have been `$nextEventDay = getDay("today");`. This was causing all the problems

give @MartyMcKeever's comment an up vote.